# AngularJS Json Editor

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I use [angular-json-editor](https://github.com/rodikh/angular-json-editor). This is controller:

```
var TaskEditCtrl = function($scope, $http, $routeParams, Notification, Task) {
    $scope.task = Task.get({id: $routeParams.taskId});
    $scope.schema = $http.get("/static/schema/schema.json");
};
```

This is template:

```
<json-editor schema="schema" startval="task.data">
```

`task.data` is `undefined` and not loaded into editor. How make it?

Comment: Is `$scope.task.data` defined?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to have the directive compiled when the data is available. You can control this using ngIf

```
<json-editor ng-if="task" schema="schema" startval="task">
```

Also the `$http.get` returns a promise, and I assume Task does the same.

```
 Task.get(...).then(function(response) { $scope.task = response.data; });
 $http.get('/static/schema/schema.json').then(function(json){$scope.schema = json;});
```

Comment: Ok. Other way. If add into plugin watcher, this can help resolve this problem?

Comment: Actually, angular-json-editor accepts promises for both schema and startval. hello from 2016 :)